# Readline: How to list all autocomplete matches on double tab?

Tags: c++, c, readline

I'm using "readline" library to create a console interface for my program. I'm able to autocomplete words using <kbd>tab</kbd>, but when I have words that share the same prefix like (car, card, carbon) it always chooses the shortest one. Here's my program (mostly taken from [link](http://cc.byexamples.com/2008/06/16/gnu-readline-implement-custom-auto-complete/)):

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

const char *words[] = {"add", "remove", "rm", "update", "child", "children", "wife", "wifes"};

void *xmalloc (int size)
{
    void *buf;
    buf = malloc (size);
    if (!buf)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: Out of memory. Exiting.\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    return buf;
}

char *dupstr (const char *str)
{
    char *temp;
    temp = (char *) xmalloc (strlen (str) + 1);
    strcpy (temp, str);
    return (temp);
}

char *my_generator (const char *text, int state)
{
    static int list_index, len;
    const char *name;

    if (!state)
    {
        list_index = 0;
        len = strlen (text);
    }

    while (name = words[list_index])
    {
        list_index++;
        if (strncmp (name, text, len) == 0) return dupstr (name);
    }

    // If no names matched, then return NULL.
    return ((char *) NULL);
}

static char **my_completion (const char *text, int start, int end)
{
    char **matches = (char **) NULL;
    if (start == 0)
    {
        matches = rl_completion_matches ((char *) text, &my_generator);
    }
    else rl_bind_key ('\t', rl_abort);
    return matches;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *buf;
    rl_attempted_completion_function = my_completion;

    while ((buf = readline(">> ")) != NULL)
    {
        rl_bind_key ('\t', rl_complete);

        if (strcmp (buf, "exit") == 0) break;
        else if (buf[0] == '\0') continue;
        else
        {
            std::cout << buf << std::endl;
            add_history (buf);
        }
    }
    free (buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to list all matches on double <kbd>tab</kbd> just like in ubuntu terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by commenting out these two lines:

```
rl_bind_key ('\t', rl_complete);
```

and:

```
else rl_bind_key ('\t', rl_abort);
```

The default completion behaviour of readline works exactly like in ubuntu terminal, one tab to complete and two tabs to list possible completions. Not sure though what's the default completion function that's binded with the tab key, from the [documentation](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/rlman_2.html#SEC36) i thought it was `rl_possible_completions` but it didn't give the same results.

Also i added the following line to `my_completion` function to prevent adding space at the end of the matched word:

```
rl_completion_append_character = '\0';
```

I removed `dupstr`function it and replaced it with the native `strdup` function instead (this has nothing to do with the auto complete problem, it's just to remove unnecessary code).

This is the final code:

```
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

const char *words[] = {"add", "remove", "rm", "update", "child", "children", "wife", "wives"};

// Generator function for word completion.
char *my_generator (const char *text, int state)
{
    static int list_index, len;
    const char *name;

    if (!state)
    {
        list_index = 0;
        len = strlen (text);
    }

    while (name = words[list_index])
    {
        list_index++;
        if (strncmp (name, text, len) == 0) return strdup (name);
    }

    // If no names matched, then return NULL.
    return ((char *) NULL);
}

// Custom completion function
static char **my_completion (const char *text, int start, int end)
{
    // This prevents appending space to the end of the matching word
    rl_completion_append_character = '\0';

    char **matches = (char **) NULL;
    if (start == 0)
    {
        matches = rl_completion_matches ((char *) text, &my_generator);
    }
    // else rl_bind_key ('\t', rl_abort);
    return matches;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *buf;
    rl_attempted_completion_function = my_completion;

    while ((buf = readline(">> ")) != NULL)
    {
        // rl_bind_key ('\t', rl_complete);

        if (strcmp (buf, "exit") == 0) break;
        else if (buf[0] == '\0')
        {
            free (buf);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << buf << std::endl;
            add_history (buf);
        }

        free (buf);
        buf = NULL;
    }
    if (buf != NULL) free (buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by razzak is almost correct, but this NULL must be added at the end of array of strings:

```
const char *words[] = {"add", "remove", "rm", "update", "child", "children", "wife", "wives", NULL};
```

Comment: Why do you need NULL at the end?

Comment: @razzak because [the docs](http://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/rlman_2.html#SEC38) say so: 'The array is terminated with a NULL pointer.'

Answer (score 0):

Some changes for nonwarning compilation in `my_generator()` function:

```
while ((name = words[list_index++]))
{
    if (strncmp (name, text, len) == 0) return strdup (name);
}
```